# Как быть с запятой в "вот например"? если далее двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация, точное-словоупотребление

> И мы не раз будем нырять из нашего средневековья в сербское **и
>   наоборот**. Потому что интересно наблюдать, размышлять! **Вот
>   например:** мы в начале XIII века гораздо более изобретательны в
>   проявлениях **пусть такого скупого, но архитектурного декора**. Мы
>   хотим видеть, как именно устроена стена, мы ищем и стремимся передать
>   ритм, для нас важна контрастность – мы хотим, чтобы солнце рисовало
>   нам тени. Симметрия и ритм – это начало всякого искусства! Но в плане
>   наши средневековые сакральные постройки всегда тяготеют к квадрату,
>   чтобы, словно собрав натяжение его углов, силу «стяжек», выстрелить в
>   небо высокими главами и колокольнями.

Выделено всё сомневающее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сомнения напрасны, на мой взгляд, всё верно.

> Потому что интересно наблюдать, размышлять! **Вот например**: мы в начале
>   XIII века гораздо более изобретательны в проявлениях **пусть такого
>   скупого, но архитектурного декора**.

Мы знаем, что вводное слово  не обособляется в начале и в конце оборота. ***Вот например*** очень похоже на присоединение (Впрочем, с какой интонацией прочитать, но если автор не поставил запятую, значит, прочитал без паузы, слово "вот" поясняется предыдущим предложением и указывает вместе с вводным словом на последующее разъяснение). Следовательно, ***вот например*** выполняет здесь роль пояснительного оборота. Проверить себя можно, убрав вводное, тогда будет понятно, к чему относится **"вот"**: *Вот мы в начале XIII века гораздо более изобретательны в проявлениях пусть такого скупого, но архитектурного декора.*- смысл очень изменился, **вот** явно относится к "мы изобретательны", у автора такого смысла не было, оно относилось именно к вводному слову, потому он и не разделил их запятыми, это оборот.

Во втором примере, я понимаю, речь не о запятых, а о словоупотреблении. А что вызывает сомнение? Скупой, но всё-таки декор (архитектурный) - всё верно.

Answer (score 2):

1) И мы не раз будем нырять из нашего средневековья в сербское **и наоборот.** 
http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_237

***И наоборот*** относится к члену предложения, нет запятой.

2) Правилами постановка двоеточия в таких случаях не фиксируется, указана только постановка **двоеточия после обобщающего слова.**

Но здесь ***вот*** относится к вводному слову, после него делается предупредительная пауза, которую желательно **обозначить двоеточием.** Кстати, возможны **два варианта** оформления (с двоеточием и запятой):

*Потому что интересно наблюдать, размышлять! **Вот например:** мы в начале XIII века гораздо более изобретательны в проявлениях пусть такого скупого, но архитектурного декора.*

*Вот мы, **например**, в начале XIII века гораздо более изобретательны в проявлениях пусть такого скупого, но архитектурного декора.*

3) Предложение желательно редактировать (*скупой, но архитектурный* — неверное противопоставление).

Как вариант:

*Вот например: мы в начале XIII века гораздо более изобретательны **в применении архитектурного декора,** хотя и очень сдержанного (умеренного), скупого.*